# Get detailed output of SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

We have an SQL Server Agent job that runs a maintenance plan to reindex all of the database on the server. Recently this has failed but the job history is not providing enough information to diagnose the problem.

In the job history it states *The job failed. The job was invoked by user foo\bar. The last step to run was step 1 (Rebuild Index).*

In the details window are multiple messages in the following form:

```
Executing query "ALTER INDEX [something] ON [a...".: 0% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2015-03-15 22:51:23.67     Source: Rebuild Index Task
```

The SQL statement that is running is truncated, and I would assume that the output of the statement is also truncated, preventing me being able to identify which particular statement has failed and why. Is there any way to extract the full text of these messages?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is there any way to extract the full text of these messages?

You can achieve it in 2 ways - Go in job step and select the Advanced tab:

a. Output to a file (<== My preferred method)

[image]

b. "Log to table" and "Include step output in history" (<== You need to trim `msdb..sysjobhistory` in long-run as the messages are stored as `nvarchar(max)` instead of `nvarchar(1024)`)

[image]

In order to see the additional logged information you need to use this stored procedure sp_help_jobsteplog or you could query the `msdb.dbo.sysjobstepslogs` table directly.

*[More info here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1394/how-to-store-longer-sql-agent-job-step-output-messages/)*

Comment: @toryan I had the same problem -- logging was ***still*** truncated, even with output to a table (method (b) above) and reading `sysjobstepslogs`.  This was the recommendation of most online discussions of this problem.  But method (a), output to a file, did ***NOT*** have this problem:  the text files are showing me all job step logging, finally without truncation!  (In my case, my job steps are `DTEXEC` commands, running SSIS packages.)  Only drawback:  only the last run is seen, unless appending to the file.  Rather than appending, I choose to live with truncation on earlier runs.

Answer (score 4):

You can get full text:

1. Go to the job
2. Right click `select properties`
3. Go the job step
4. Select `step` and click on `edit` button
5. Select `advanced`. Here you can see the log path.

Now its simple follow the path.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was most easily visible from

1. expanding Management
2. Maintenance Plans
3. finding the maintenance plan we had set up for rebuilding indexes,
4. right click,  view
   history

The error message listed here, under "Error message:" was not truncated, like I had seen elsewhere.